# myParticleEmitter weirdness (creates artifact at 0.0) while drawing from point A to point B

Tags: sprite-kit

A little weirdness here, I have a particle emitter added to an SKShapeNode
(the particles should follow the line)

yet when it does it also has a bit of particle system sitting at 0,0
Ive moved it up a little so you can see it better

**Any thoughts to how this might be happening?**,
I'll post the code below, but still I cant find anything, I have tested with other textures setting setStrokeTexture -  incase the line is making some sort of sneaky extra part - but no it seems fine....and creates a line between the sprites...

**in LinkWithNumberClass** //SKSpriteNode SKPhysicsContactDelegate

```
if (isUsingParticles == YES) {
    
    //create new line
    SKShapeNode*lineNode02 = [SKShapeNode node];
    lineNode02.lineWidth = 10;
    lineNode02.name = @"lineNode";

    //clear line of colour
    lineNode02.fillColor = [SKColor clearColor];
    lineNode02.strokeColor = [SKColor clearColor];
    
    //create the path the line follows (line joins two sprites)
    CGMutablePathRef pathToDraw = CGPathCreateMutable();
    CGPathMoveToPoint(pathToDraw, NULL, spriteA.position.x, spriteA.position.y);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(pathToDraw, NULL, spriteB.position.x, spriteB.position.y);
    lineNode02.path = pathToDraw;
    [self addChild:lineNode02];
    
    //Add Particles 
    myParticlePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:_parName ofType:@"sks"];
    myParticleEmitter = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithFile:myParticlePath];
    [self addChild:myParticleEmitter];
    
     CGFloat distancebtween = SDistanceBetweenPoints(spriteA.position, spriteB.position);
    myParticleEmitter.particlePositionRange = CGVectorMake( particleLength,0 );
    myParticleEmitter.position = CGPointMake(distancebtween/2, +10);
    self->myParticleEmitter.targetNode = self.scene;
   
    int particleTime = 3;
     SKAction *followTrack =
     [SKAction followPath:pathToDraw
     asOffset:YES
     orientToPath:YES
     duration:particleTime];
    
     SKAction *forever = [SKAction repeatActionForever:followTrack];
     self->myParticleEmitter.particleAction = forever;
}
```

**In Game Layer**

```
    -(void)addStaticLinkedSpriteWithParticles
{
    twoSpritesWithParticlesBridge =
    [[LinkWithNumber alloc]initWithlinkSpriteA:@"Object"
                                       spriteB:@"Object"
                             andPlistAnimation:@"Aniamtions"
                                   distbetween:100
                                  hasParticles:YES
                                ParticlesNamed:@"Fire"];
      [self addChild:self->twoSpritesWithParticlesBridge];
}
```

With thanks :)
Natalie.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In the end I go it to work not needing to draw a line at all.

- Create particle system Position on SpriteA
- find distance between
  the two sprites (to get length for particles)
- Adjust length of the particles in emitter properties
- reposition the
  particles so they are centered between the two sprites

  ```
      if (isUsingParticles == YES) {

  //create particles
  myParticlePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:_parName ofType:@"sks"];
  myParticleEmitter = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithFile:myParticlePath];
  [self addChild:myParticleEmitter];//try moving it to the line node

  //find length needed for particles
   CGFloat distancebtween = SDistanceBetweenPoints(spriteA.position, spriteB.position);

  //Adjust length of particles
  myParticleEmitter.particlePositionRange = CGVectorMake( particleLength,0 );

  //center particles between the two sprites
  myParticleEmitter.position = CGPointMake(spriteA.position.x+distancebetween/2, spriteA.position.y);
  myParticleEmitter.targetNode = self.scene;
  ```

  }

Hope it helps someone else :)